# Numbers divisible by $n$ in the interval $[k,m]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisibility

If I denote by $\alpha$ the number of numbers divisible by $n$ in the interval $[k,m]$ it seems that this formula already works

$$\left\lfloor\frac mn\right\rfloor-\Big\lceil\frac kn\Big\rceil+1=\alpha$$

but it's not clear to me why it works, and I haven't found a book that explains it, maybe it's too obvious but I can't see it.  Can someone explain or give me some bibliography?

Comment: Note $\left\lfloor\frac{m}{n}\right\rfloor\cdot n$ is the largest multiple of $n$ which is $\le m$ and $\left\lceil\frac{k}{n}\right\rceil\cdot n$ is the smallest multiple of $n$ which is $\ge k$ (e.g., as shown in [First number $\ge n$ that is divisible by $k$?](/q/1270734/602049) and [Lowest multiple of $n$ over a certain threshold, $y$.](/q/120104/602049), ...

Comment: (cont.) found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Bk%2Cm%5D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cleft(%5Cleft%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%7Bm%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright%5Crfloor%5Ccdot%20n-%5Cleft%5Clceil%5Cfrac%7Bk%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright%5Crceil%5Ccdot%20n%5Cright)%2B1%24&p=2)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x\in [k,m]$ is divisible by $n$ iff $x = yn$ for some $y$ where $\frac{k}n \leq y \leq \frac{m}n$. Hence the desired number is the number of integers $y$ in the interval $[\frac{k}n, \frac{m}n].$ $y$ is an integer, so $y\leq \frac{m}n$ implies $y\leq \lfloor \frac{m}n\rfloor$ and $\frac{k}n\leq y$ implies $\lceil \frac{k}n\rceil\leq y.$ Hence since y is an integer, the inequality is equivalent to $\lceil \frac{k}n\rceil\leq y \leq \lfloor \frac{m}n\rfloor,$ and from this one can obtain the given formula.

Answer (score 0):

Count the integers in the interval:
$$
\left[\frac kn,\frac mn\right]
$$
The lowest integer is:
$$
k^*=\left\lceil\frac kn\right\rceil
$$
the highest integer is:
$$
m^*=\left\lfloor\frac mn\right\rfloor
$$
Therefore the count becomes
$$
\alpha=m^*-k^*+1
$$